# Fps not high enough in a simple 2-D game using Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Am doing a simple 2-D pong game using Unity.

I'm facing a problem now that when I run the game on pc everything moves smoothly however, when I try testing it on a mobile the ball does not move so  smooth. It appears as if it is jumping not moving.

If I lower its acceleration it works ok but the game becomes really boring.
If I raise the acceleration a little bit then this problem rises.

Is it possible to to raise the default fps for the game?

Here's the script for the Ball:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement2 : MonoBehaviour {


    void Start () {

    }
    public float ballspeedx = 2, ballspeedy = 0F;


    void Update () {
       float accx = ballspeedx * Time.fixedDeltaTime    ,accy=ballspeedy*Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        gameObject.transform.position=new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x+accx,gameObject.transform.position.y+(accy),0);

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {

        if (collider.name == "redpong" || collider.name == "bluepong" || collider.name == "east" || collider.name == "west")
        {


            ballspeedx *= -1;

        }
        if (collider.name == "north" || collider.name == "south" || collider.name == "purplepong" || collider.name == "greenpong")
        {
            Debug.Log("N S Borders");
            ballspeedy *= -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the ball's acceleration independent of the framerate? What is the framerates on the mobile device you are testing on? Can you share code that demonstrates how you're applying acceleration to the ball?

Comment: There was a bug with Android on an older version of Unity. If you aren't using the latest version (5.3.5) try downloading the new one.

Comment: @JonathonOgden thanks for the quick reply... Am not sure if the acceleration independent of the framerate am a beginner in unity. Am testing the game on different mobiles and they all have the same results (the ball not moving smoothly). the script for the ball movement is :  http://pastebin.com/T5GKhfRH

Comment: @omargamal8 added your code from that link to your initial post. At a quick glance, you're using `fixedDeltaTime` which defines the interval in seconds that fixed (called every frame, so locked to frame rates - if it wasn't locked to frame rates, the Ball might not move smoothly) updates including physics, occurs. What I think you might need to do is use `Time.deltaTime` instead which gives you the time elapsed since the last update.